# given the same frequency, why does the pwm period decrease when the resolution decreases

Tags: rust, esp32, hal, esp-idf-sys

I've got an ESP32-C3 and the following Rust code. Retaining the frequency but decreasing the resolution, I expected the accuracy of the pulse width to decrease but it unfortunately also decreases the period (speeds up). I expected the period to stay the same as I thought it is fully determined by the frequency and not by the resolution.

```
let pwm_pin = peripherals.pins.gpio10.into_output().unwrap();
let config = TimerConfig::default().frequency((50.Hz()).into()).resolution(Resolution::Bits13);
let timer = Timer::new(peripherals.ledc.timer0, &config)?;
let mut channel = Channel::new(peripherals.ledc.channel0, &timer, pwm_pin)?;

// set duty cycle to 50%
let percent = 50;
let duty = ((channel.get_max_duty() as f64 / 100.0) * percent as f64) as u32;
channel.set_duty(duty);
```

**13bit** produce a PWM period of 20ms, duty cycle of 50% and a high pulse width of 10ms.

[image: Resolution::Bits13]

Decreasing the resolution to `Resolution::Bits8` has the unexpected effect of not just reducing the duty cycle granularity but also decreasing the period.

**8bit** produce a PWM period of 250us, duty cycle of 50% and a high pulse width of 124us.

[image: Resolution::Bits8]

How do I calculate the period from any given frequency and resolution. All I found online is references to `period = 1/frequency` which does not take the resolution into account.

Comment: That looks like a bug the library you're using (or the hardware). `period = 1/frequency` is not something that should be influenced by the resolution of the timer cause it's the definition of both values.

Comment: Maybe it is using the current resolution as a basis to compute the frequency? Try swapping them around: `imerConfig::default().resolution(Resolution::Bits8).frequency((50.Hz()).into());`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on GitHub lifted the veil on what is going on here...

> A simple reverse calculation:
> 8bit -> 255 = 250us | x = 20ms => x = y > * 20ms/250us => y = 80 & x = 20400. Because 20400 > 13Bits our initial assumption that 255 = 250us was not true but already a bit lower. but
> its still a factor of 80 down. the problem with low frequency's
> compared to high input clocks is you either need a high resolution
> counter ( eg many bits) or divide down your clock source further
> otherwise you fill your register to fast. ( counting to 255 is faster
> than counting to 20400 with the same counting speed) but sometimes you
> are hardware limited and can not reach all desired output speeds ( you
> are already dividing down your input clock by max divider). So if it
> hits a hardware limit and cant translate it it has to for example rise
> the frequency respectively.

Link to the discussion https://github.com/esp-rs/esp-idf-sys/issues/154